# endless loop with player and enemy attacking each other

Tags: python

I keep getting an endless loop when i try and fight the player vs a enemy. It is to a much bigger texted based dungeon crawler that allows you to get items and enemies get stronger as you go.

```
import random
import sys

player = {
    'name': 'unknown',
    'class': 'unknown',
    # 'location': r1,
    'HP': 100,
    'ap': 1,
    'dp': 1,
    'mp': 1,
    'ap_item': 1,
    'dp_item': 1,
    'ms_itme': 1
}

enemy1 = {
    'HP': 50,
    'ap': .2,
    'dp': .2,
    'name': 'Rat'
}

enemy2 = {
    'HP': 50,
    'ap': .2,
    'dp': .2,
    'name': 'Skeleton'
}

enemy5 = {
    'HP': 75,
    'ap': .5,
    'dp': .5,
    'name': 'Skeleton pack'
}

def enemy_attack(oppo1, player):
    while player['HP'] > 0:
        if oppo1['ap'] == .2:
            rand_damage = random.randint(8, 25)
            attack_damage = rand_damage * player['dp']
            final_damage = attack_damage * player['dp_item']
            player['HP'] - final_damage
            print(final_damage, "damage!")
            break
        elif oppo1['ap'] == .5:
            rand_damage = random.randint(16, 50)
            attack_damage = rand_damage * player['dp']
            final_damage = attack_damage * player['dp_item']
            player['HP'] - final_damage
            print(final_damage, "damage!")
            break
        else:
            print("enemy_attack is wrong")
            break

def attack(player, oppo1):
    while oppo1['HP'] > 0:
        rand_damage = random.randint(8, 32)
        attack = rand_damage / player['ap']
        attack_damage = attack / player['ap_item']
        final_damage = attack_damage * oppo1['dp']
        player['HP'] - final_damage
        print(final_damage, " damage!")
        break

def fight(player, oppo1):
    while (player['HP'] > 0) and (oppo1['HP'] > 0):
        print(player['name'], "attacks", oppo1['name'])
        attack(player, oppo1)
        if oppo1['HP'] <= 0:
            print(player['name'], "is winner")
            oppo1['HP'] = 0
            print(player['name'], "HP:", player['HP'])
            print(oppo1['name'], "HP:", oppo1['HP'])
            break
        else:
            print(oppo1['name'], "attacks", player['name'])
            enemy_attack(oppo1, player)
            if player['HP'] <= 0:
                print(oppo1['name'], "is winner")
                player['HP'] = 0
                print(player['name'], "HP:", player['HP'])
                print(oppo1['name'], "HP:", oppo1['HP'])
                print("game_over", player['name'])

def encounter(player, oppo1):
    print("You have come to a door, you open the door and slowly enter.")
    fight(player, oppo1)
    input('Press any key to continue')

def main():
    print("encounter 1")
    encounter(player, enemy1)
    input("press enter to continue")
    print("encounter 1")
    encounter(player, enemy2)
    input("press enter to continue")
    print("encounter 1")
    encounter(player, enemy5)
    input("press enter to continue")

main()
```

could really use some help. I have tried a bunch of different ideas to be able to have the multipliers and all the fight logic, but it just endlessly loops the player and enemy attacking each other.

Answer (score 1):

## The reason for the never-ending fight

In several places you have this:

```
player['HP'] - final_damage
```

This code doesn't store any values inside `player` - it just subtracts the HP and then throws the value away. To store the value you need an equals sign in there:

```
player['HP'] -= final_damage
```

It also appears that you don't try and decrease the opponent's HP anywhere. For that you would need

```
oppo1['HP'] -= final_damage
```

at some point in the code.

Because the player's HP and the opponent's HP never decrease, the condition in the `while` loop in the `fight` function is always true, and the fight carries on forever.

## On while loops and break statements

By the way... while I'm commenting, I noticed something else that you can do to improve your code.

In the `attack` function you have this:

```
while oppo1['HP'] > 0:
    # ...
    break
```

This `break` statement will make the while loop exit the first time it is run, so you may as well just use an `if` statement.

```
if oppo1['HP'] > 0:
    # ...
```

Hope this helps!